# Eclipse JDT generate a wrong ast when lombok in project

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, lombok, eclipse-jdt

I need a right CompilationUnit from Java file ,but eclipse jdt generate a wrong ast，because the Java file has lombok.

I see Eclipse JDT source code,find ASTConverter convert the right CompilationUnitDeclaration to wrong CompilationUnit.

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.convert(CompilationUnitDeclaration, char[])
```

I find the ASTConverter use source code position to get infromation,but source code don't have.
org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.convert(StringLiteral)

```
public Expression convert(org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.StringLiteral expression) {
    if (expression instanceof StringLiteralConcatenation) {
        return convert((StringLiteralConcatenation) expression);
    }
    int length = expression.sourceEnd - expression.sourceStart + 1;
    int sourceStart = expression.sourceStart;
    StringLiteral literal = new StringLiteral(this.ast);
    if (this.resolveBindings) {
        this.recordNodes(literal, expression);
    }
    literal.internalSetEscapedValue(new String(this.compilationUnitSource, sourceStart, length));
    literal.setSourceRange(expression.sourceStart, expression.sourceEnd - expression.sourceStart + 1);
    return literal;
}
```

my code

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS10);
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setEnvironment(classpathEntries, sourcepathEntries, sourcepathEncodings, includeRunningVMBootclasspath);
parser.setResolveBindings(resolveBindings);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(false);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
parser.createASTs(sourceFilePaths.toArray(new String[0]), encodings.toArray(new String[0]), wellKnownKeys,requestor, null);
```

source code

```
package com.test;

import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
public class DataExample {
    private int age;
}
```

right CompilationUnitDeclaration

```
package com.test;
import lombok.Setter;
public @Setter class DataExample {
  private int age;
  public DataExample() {
    super();
  }
  public @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all") void setAge(final int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

The last generation wrong CompilationUnit

```
package com.test;
import lombok.Setter;
@Setter public class DataExample {
  @java.lang.SuppressWarnings(@Setter) void setAge(  int age){
  }
  private int age;
}
}
```

Does ASTParser require some configuration ? and how to modify ASTConverter

Comment: I don't think JDT has a chance to create the expected AST from structures that have been modified during compilation by lombok (most likely by undocumented internals of JDT). If anyone can fix this issue, then the Eclipse-lombok integration has to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I found the Eclipse ASTView to be working,and  generate a right tree.I sew the source code,IJavaElement input = JavaUI.getEditorInputJavaElement(editorInput); but jdt input from strings,What's the difference between the JDT and the Eclipse ASTView other than input?Why can the Eclipse AST get the correct AST?

Comment: If ASTView shows a correct tree, than perhaps the problem is just an issue of the `toString()` rendering of a "mostly-correct" structure? Have you checked if the AST actually contains any wrong nodes?

Comment: Dear, do you find a solution for this? I have the same problem, and I need a solution too

Comment: I was thinking in disable the lombok agent temporally, but I don't know if it's possible

Comment: It seems lombok implements an eclipseAgent module and it will inject some logic into AST processing. but when I add -javaagent:lombok.jar, it reports error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lombok/eclipse/EcjAugments
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTConverter.fixRetrieveRightBraceOrSemiColonPosition(ASTConverter.java:688)